# Saving an hash as a string, reform it later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to be able to save a params[:object] hash in a text field of a drafts table, to keep this hash saved and pull it out later. I want to know if it's possible to do so that I get a hash out later, with functionality.

Right now, when I am saving a post in here, so I have the following line:

```
 @draft = user.drafts.build(:content => params[:post])
```

This saves the params[:post] hash as:

```
 "--- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess \ntitle: asdfasdfasdf\ncontent: \"\"\ndiscussion_id: \"87\"\ndraft: \"false\"\n"
```

If I find the draft (ie d = Draft.find(1)) and then I try to pull this hash out, I just get the string value here.

Is there some way I can reform this into a hash? Or is there a better way to go about saving the params hash in the first place?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the class method [`serialize` in `ActiveRecord::Base`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Saving+arrays%2C+hashes%2C+and+other+non-mappable+objects+in+text+columns):

```
class Draft < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :content, Hash
end
```

It should save a fair amount of time over doing this yourself!

Comment: It was what I was going to post, it seems perfect for this situation

Comment: Agreed. I wasn't clear on whether @Jay's already half-using `serialize` or not and for some reason wants to manipulate the string data before it's unserialized. That question seems to come up with some regularity :^)